# Como puedo saber el número de commits de cada uno de los contribuidores?

Tags: git, git-commit

Necesito determinar el número de `commits` de mis usuarios en el repo.

Algo como:

```
git log --commit por usuario.
pepe 23 commits.
juan 20 commit
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para saber los números de `commits` y que mensajes se añadieron en los `commits`, se debe realizar la siguiente instrucción:

```
git shortlog
```

Si quieres ver los `commits` de cada uno de los usuarios del repo, debes hacer esto:

```
git shortlog | grep "nombre usuario"
```

Answer (score 4):

Para conocer el listado de `commits` hechos por un usuario en particular (llamado usuario-git) se debe ejecutar:

`git log --author="usuario-git" --pretty=oneline`

eso te va a dar un listado como el siguiente:

`3598e4cfcc9474595e84c2991554275f8eadcc10 Add achivement and response
1ee573ee78221ac73d08fa3d0572dfedbcbd9466 Add Assessment section
22282ac459e54a70e723d3b3da058d7a8ba8a552 Enhance of style of the doc`

En donde cada `commit` realizado por este usuario va a ser reflejado con **una sola linea**.

**Si lo que se desea es número de `commits` del usuario**, se puede agregar  `| wc -l`, (llamado pipear o entubar) y se debe obtener algo como lo siguiente:

`git log --author="usuario-git" --pretty=oneline | wc -l`

Y eso te va a arrojar el número de `commit` de ese usuario en específico.

Por otra parte, en github se puede listar los `commit` hechos por un usuario en particular, de la siguiente manera:

`https://github.com/usuario-git/proyecto-git/commits/master?author=usuario-git`

Espero sea de utilidad.